# General formula for sinusoidal taylor series centered at any a?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I understand that to find a taylor series centred at a particular a value you need to find a formula for the nth derivative, but this is tricky for cos(x) and sin(x). Is it possible to have a formula to memorize for a certain function in which you just have to put in the a value? Or does it need to be evaluated every time?

If that's not possible, are there a formulas for the nth derivative of common functions, such as e^x, sin(x), cos(x), etc?

Comment: The exponential function $e^x$ is its own derivative, so it is its own $n$th derivative for all $n$. The successive derivatives of $\sin$ and $\cos$ follow the repeating pattern $\sin x, \cos x, -\sin x, -\cos x, \sin x, \ldots$.

Comment: But how can you describe the nth derivative of sin or cos? I know the pattern repeats, but how does this help?

Comment: If $n$ is even the $n$-th derivative of $\sin x$ is $(-1)^{n/2}\sin x$.  If $n$ is odd then the $n$-th derivative of $\sin x$ is $(-1)^{(n-1)/2}\cos x$. There are similar formulas for $\cos$.